# Exclude date in timestamp from Firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I just want to ask, is there a way to exclude the date in Timestamp from Firestore? Like, I only want the hour and minutes to be displayed.

For example, the output of my code below is **"Date: Tue Aug 24 23:59:00 GMT+08:00 2021"**

```
holder.binding.tvTimeIn.setText(employeeModel.getTime_in().toDate().toString());
```

And I only want the **"23:59:00"** part to be displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are storing in the database is a Firestore [Timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/Timestamp) object that represents a point in time with nanoseconds precision. If you want to display only the time, then you have to format it like this:

```
Date date = employeeModel.getTime_in().toDate()
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
String time = sdf.format(date);
holder.binding.tvTimeIn.setText(time);
```

Alternatively, you can store in the database only the time in a String format, if this is your requirement.

Comment: Firestore `Timestamp` is not directly compatible to `java.time`, why?

Comment: @deHaar Because there is no inheritance relationship between those classes.

Comment: @AlexMamo Is there one between that `Timestamp` and a `java.util.Date`? I only found that `toDate()` method, which appears to be more like a conversion than an inheritance relationship? I was expecting something like `toInstant()`...

Comment: @deHaar Yes, that's a conversion and not an inheritance relationship. The [toDate()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/Timestamp#toDate()), returns a new Date that corresponds to the timestamp.

Comment: Ok, that means chain-calling `someTimestamp.toDate().toInstant()` would build up the bridge to `java.time`... Yes, I had planned to fully understand this and upvote afterwards ;-) May be time for that, now.

Comment: @deHaar Yes, that's correct. But be aware that [toInstant()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#toInstant--) is only available starting from Java 8. It's not available in earlier versions.

Comment: @AlexMamo Sure, I know... There are backports to Java 6 and 7, but those would require another conversion in between. However, the matter has been clarified (to me), thanks.